# Сумма TextBox циклом

Tags: c#, циклы, form

Необходимо получить сумму всех значений Textbox'ов. Можно их, конечно, конвертировать и складывать без цикла, но их 6 штук. Хотелось бы как-то уменьшить. Пробовала так:

```
foreach (TextBox textBox in groupBox1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            sum = +Convert.ToDouble(textBox.Text);
        }
```

Не получается. После выполнения sum равна последнему. Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sum = +Convert.ToDouble(textBox.Text);
```

я бы поменял на

```
sum += Convert.ToDouble(textBox.Text);
```

В комментариях мне подказывают, что нужно поясниить ответ.
Дело в том, что (и я уверен, что это просто опечатка) Вы использовали "оператор" =+ в выражении, в котором хотели бы делать суммирование. Для этого служит оператор += (без кавычек, потому что такой оператор в языке действительно есть).

А когда написано "=+" - то это интерпретируется как "сдалть знак + (то есть, ничегонее менять) для конвертированного значения и присвоить". Вместо того, чтобы складывать последовательные значения.

В результате, на каждом шаге цикла происходит присвоение, а не суммирование. И в результате самого последнего присвоения sum равна последнему значанию.

Comment: Вообще, из "хороших практик", лучше не пользоваться Convert.ToDouble() вне try-catch, потому что при малейшей описке Convert бросит исключение. Есть полезный метод TryParse(), который лишен этого недостатка. Он возвращает значение, указывающее, успешно ли выполнено преобразование. Можно в зависимости от этого значения "покрасить" текст в текстбоксе в красный цвет, если в нём кто то написал букву о вместо нуля :-)

Comment: Вы лучше объясните человеку в чем отличие `=+` от `+=`, ибо такой ответ решит задачу, но вот поймет ли автор вопроса в будущем из за чего такое произошло, вряд ли.

Comment: я уверен, что это просто опечатка. По моему, ReSharper даже отдавливает такие опечатки в VS.

Comment: Здесь явно не опечатка, а незнание и да, не у всех есть решарпер. Ну а так, ответ ваш, дело ваше)